# How do I get a square image to scale up evenly if the phone screen size increases?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I am having trouble figuring out how to set up the constraints on an image view.

[image]

I have an imageView of size 155*155. I want the view to remain a square shape but scale up if the iPhone screen size increases to 6 or 6+. I can constrain the distance to the bottom of the container and the sides of the imageView to the sides of the main view. This should stretch the width but is there a way to make the height increase by the same amount? Any pointers would be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an aspect ratio constraint by ctrl + dragging from your image INTO your image.

[image]

This basically tells that you want to maintain the current aspect ratio as your other constraints force a change in the width or in the height.